How to add authentication system in react native expo - using Tabs and Stack navigators
I'm making an expo app that require user to login or sign up , if he doesn't login or sign up the welcome page shows up which has sign in/up options , I am using Tabs and Stacks to navigate between pages here is the files structure which is playing a main role here:

as you can see i use legendapp state management system in this app , here is the code of the setup file ( just testing ) ```
import { observable } from "@legendapp/state";
export const appStateLegend = observable({
  userAuthToken: "SOME_RANDOM_AUTH",
});

and here is the app/_layout.jsx code:
import Stack from "expo-router/stack";

const Layout = () => {

  return (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ animation: "ios" }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="welcome" options={{ headerShown: false}} /> 
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="(tabs_pages)" />
      <Stack.Screen name="[id]" />
      <Stack.Screen name="profile" />
    </Stack>
  );
};
export default Layout;

what i want to implement using when first user launch the app, check if userAuthToken state exist or not (later i will use mmkv for faster reads and caching ) , if it exists , then show the (tabs_pages) pages which you can see on the app/(tabs_pages) , if it doesn't exist then shows the welcome page which has options to sign in/up
NOTE: i tried using the documentation for react navigator that implements this way:
return ( 
   {isAuthenticated ? ( 
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="(tabs_pages)" />
      <Stack.Screen name="[id]" />
      <Stack.Screen name="profile" />
      </Stack>
  ) : (
    <Stack screenOptions={{ animation: "ios" }}>
      <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="welcome" />
      <Stack.Screen name="signin" />
      <Stack.Screen name="signup" />
    </Stack>
  )}
, it eather doesn't work or throws errors **like Attempted to navigate before mounting the Root Layout component**




